# Access QML Profiler via qml / js / c++ code

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, qml, qt-creator

I would like to access the caller/callee list from QML Profiler programmatically, does anyone know whether there is a way to do this?

I have read documentation and scanned other stackoverflow questions, but they deal with how to use QML Profiler. E.g. http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-2.6/creator-qml-performance-monitor.html. However they do not list a way to programmatically access it.

I'm looking for something like this:

```
console.profile()
...
// call some functions (which call other functions etc.)
...
console.profileEnd()
// >> be able to navigate the calls made <<
```

I am aware it probably will not be this simple, however I would appreciate any help from more experienced users who could point me in the right direction.

Comment: I've never tried something like this, but a good starting point might be a [`qqmlprofilerservice_p.h`](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtdeclarative/source/8e1b88e457cbee0000d5956f2ff5a98724c2d3e4:src/qml/debugger/qqmlprofilerservice_p.h)  — this is a private Qt header that you should be able to include and use. See where it takes you. Checking the Qt creator sources should be informative as well.

Comment: You can start from here - http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-debugging.html#qml-debugging-infrastructure. But as for me I would start from the source code - $QTDIR/Src/qtdeclarative/tools/qmlprofiler